Rails Cookies not updating on other pages
Is there a way in Rails to delete/reset a particular cookie when the value has been changed on one page?
So I have 10 tabs, if the cookie is changed on tab 1 it doesn't update on the rest of the tabs unless I refresh a second time.
I am trying to reset that cookie on all the pages.
Please if someone can help me with this.

yes, if you change cookie on 1 open tab, on other tabs they stay the same until page refresh, in other browsers they stay the same until page refresh

Cookies are shared across tabs, they are stored in a file in a browser, what do you mean you need a refresh? Please, provide more detailed information of the problem: what you do and what doesn't work

@GProst not really. document.cookie will return the cookies as they existed when the page was rendered on most browsers. The stored cookies are only used when sending new requests. What's wrong here is a completely unrealistic expectation.

Interesting, thank you, I guess I never encountered such a problem, perhaps because I work with SPAs mostly, seemed unexpected to me that it would require page refresh.

No
There isn't a way to do this in any web framework.
In browsers cookies are per request cycle. Cookies are after all just a header that's sent back and forth in HTTP requests and stored in the client so the next time they send a request they include it. There is no peristent connection that keeps the document cookies updated from the server after the page finishes rendering.
In general clients can do whatever they want with cookies and the server (and by extension you as a developer) have very little say in how they do it.
If you need a way to store arbitrary data in the client across browser tabs you can use local storage. If you need to use a live updated value from the server on the page you would either use polling which is sending repeated AJAX requests (imagine a kid in the back seat on a long drive) or WebSockets (ActionCable in Rails) which provides a two way connection.
See what is the XY Problem.
